# В чем писать программы для контроллера Лего?

Tags: микроконтроллеры

У меня есть контроллер от механик лего 2006 года. Какая программа нужна чтобы программировать данный девайс?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Программа для разработки на этом контроллере должна прилагаться в диске вместе с устройством. Источник: https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/nxt-g-the-development-environment-supplied-with-lego-mindstorms-nxt-g/

Comment: https://www.lego.com/ru-ru/themes/mindstorms/downloads

Comment: благодарю за помощь. заняли первое место на конкурсе в техе за конструкцию вертикального ствола с лифтом ;)